# Not including field names in validation error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

If I have the following validation:

```
validates_inclusion_of :dob, :in => Date.new(1900)..Time.now.years_ago(18).to_date, :message => "You must be 18 or older to register"
```

The actual message on the site that shows up is:

"Dob You must be 18 or older to register"

Is there any way not to include the column name at the beginning of the message?

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I use the [custom-err-msg plugin](http://github.com/gumayunov/custom-err-msg/tree/master). It's pretty easy to get up and running, just read the README.

Comment: no magic built in :dont_include_field_name flag or anything, eh? :) Thanks for the plugin suggestion - I'll check it out. +1

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I developed the gem.

I feel existing solutions are hacks, and I developed this gem to avoid such hacks.

https://github.com/lulalala/adequate_errors

After installing the gem, set the error message in your locale yaml file like this:

```
en:
  activemodel
    adequate_errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            dob:
              inclusion: "You must be 18 or older to register"
```

And then accessing `model.errors.adequate.messages` will have the message without attribute prefix.