# Rails 3: How not to include column's name in a validation message without plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following validation:

```
validates_presence_of :price, :message => "my message"
```

and I get the following error when the price is blank:

> Price my message

Is there a way not to include the column name (`price`) in the message ?

I tried to do:

```
validates_presence_of :price, :message => "^ my message"
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320145/not-including-field-names-in-validation-error-messages), but it didn't work for me. I got the following message:

> Price ^ my message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ^ technique is defined in the [dynamic_form](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form) gem in Rails 3. Add that to your Gemfile, run `bundle update`, and it should work. That also lets you just put <%= f.error_messages %> in your forms to avoid a lot of extra work formatting the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and most flexible way is to write your own helper for form fields. Showing user input errors varies from application to application and from layout to layout.

```
# lib/required_attributes.rb
module ActiveModel
  module Validations
    module ClassMethods

      # ruby-1.9.2-head > Product.required_attributes
      #  => [:publisher_symbol_code, :price] 
      def required_attributes
        presence_validators = self.validators.find_all {|v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator }
        presence_validators.map(&:attributes).flatten
      end

    end
  end
end


# application_helper.rb:

def mark_as_required
  content_tag :span, '*', :class => :required
end


def form_field_for(object, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  attributes = args.map(&:to_sym)
  field_contents = capture(&block)
  classes = "form-field clear #{options[:class]}"

  if options[:hint]
    field_contents << content_tag(:p, options[:hint], :class => :inline_hint)
  end

  # Are there any required attributes?
  any_attribute_required = (object.class.required_attributes & attributes).present?

  if options[:label]
    object_name = object.class.to_s.underscore  # 'product'
    label_contents = "#{options[:label]}: #{mark_as_required if any_attribute_required}".html_safe
    label_html = label(object_name, attributes.first, label_contents, :class => 'form-label fl-space2')
    field_contents = label_html + field_contents
  end

  errors = attributes.inject([]) do |mem, attrib|
    mem << object.errors[attrib]
    mem
  end.flatten.compact.uniq

  if errors.present?
    classes << ' error' 
    field_contents << content_tag(:p, errors.join(', '), :class => :inline_errors)
  end

  content_tag(:div, field_contents, :class => classes)
end
```

And then in view:

```
= form_field_for @product, :publisher_symbol, :label => "Symbol", :hint => "pick a product symbol" do
    = product_form.text_field :publisher_symbol, :size => 70
```

When there is a group of inputs where error can occur for any field, you can group them as follows:

```
= form_field_for @product, :publication_year, :publication_month, :publication_day, :label => "Publication date" do
  = product_form.text_field :publication_year, :class => 'text fl', :size => 5
  = product_form.text_field :publication_month, :class => 'text fl', :size => 5
  = product_form.text_field :publication_day, :class => 'text fl', :size => 5
```

When an error occurs, your view looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-field clear error">
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <label class="form-label fl-space2" for="product_publisher_symbol">Symbol: <span class="required">*</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <input class="text fl" id="product_publisher_symbol" name="product[publisher_symbol]" size="70" type="text" value="">
  </div>                       
  <p class="inline_hint">pick a product symbol</p>
  <p class="inline_errors">can't be blank</p>
</div>
```

This code needs some refactoring, but you get the idea. If you're more lazy than me and don't want to type 'form_field_for' in all your views, then create a custom form builder:)